# Getting connection closed by host for scp cmd [MAC]

Tags: macos, scp

I am trying to copy folder from my Linux Ubuntu to my Mac book using scp.
My mac book is at remote place and i am having telnet connection with it

I am running following cmd on this telnet connection to get files from my linux machine to mac machine. but i am getting error connection closed.

```
$ scp -r root@11.11.11.11:/home/abc /abc 
Connection closed by 11.11.11.11
```

what will be cause of this problem?